# Symfony 3 Form Types internal server error: type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle... must be an instance of AppBundle\Form\FromEvent...

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I'm trying to create an todo-list element.
This is my list element class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Alan
 * Date: 03-Feb-17
 * Time: 3:18 AM
 */

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Todos")
 */
class Todos
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=100)
     */
    private $categoryId;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=100)
     */
    private $userId;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=100)
     */
    private $init_date;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=100)
     */
    private $comp_date;

    //SETTERS AND GETTERS....

}
```

For this I have generated a **formType**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use ....

class TodosType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Nazwa',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'name-pick'
            )
        ))
        ->add('categoryId', HiddenType::class)
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FromEvent $e){
            $e->getData()->setUserId($this->user->getId());
            $e->getData()->setInitDate($this->timestamp(new \DateTime()));
        });
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Todos'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_todos';
    }

    public function __construct($storage)
    {
        $this->user = $storage->getToken()->getUser();
    }
}
```

And a Service to get the users Id:

```
app.form.todos:
            class: AppBundle\Form\TodosType
            arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
            tags:
                - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_todos }
```

---

Now in my Twig I have it listed like so in order to have the category id values assigned properly

```
{ form_start(form) }}
                            {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
                            {{ form_widget(form.categoryId, {'value': thisCat[0].id}) }}
                            {# TODO: FIND A BETTER WAY TO SEND THE categoryId#}
                            {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Which on submit is `serializeArray()'d` and send to my Ajax Controllers method which isn't supposed to do much other then to assign the values and insert them into the database:

```
/**
     * @Route("/ajax/addTodo", name="AddTodoAjax")
     */
    public function AddTodoAjax(Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(TodosType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()){
            $todo = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($todo);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->json($todo->getId());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now the problem is, running the system in this configuration produces an **500 (Internal Server Error)** with error content being:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Form\TodosType::AppBundle\Form{closure}() must be an
>   instance of AppBundle\Form\FromEvent, instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent given (500 Internal Server Error)

---

This is the first time I've had such an issue.

I tried looking for the question here but all the similar problems are nothing but...well similar.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
All help would be amazing.

Comment: FormEvent vs FromEvent ... Can you spot the difference?

Comment: Ha Ha Cerad. +1 for the comment and helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form type, you have

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FromEvent $e){
```

That needs to be

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $e){
```